# Excel autosize text to fit shape

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add some VBA to a multiple chart template to autosize  title text to fit textbox. This now runs, but doesn't make any changes to text box ...

```
Sub TextBox()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape

' loop through sheets in this workbook
 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 ' loop through Chartobjects in sheet
   For Each shp In ws.Shapes

    If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        With shp.TextFrame2
            strTxt = .TextRange
            .DeleteText
            .WarpFormat = msoWarpFormat1
            .WordWrap = True
            .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
            .TextRange = strTxt
        End With
    End If
   Next shp
  Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't set TB to be anything before trying to use it

Comment: Have tried this Set TB = Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1"))

Comment: @tj123 what type of text box are you using in your file  ?

Comment: Its the drawing version ...

Comment: ActiveX controls are of type msoOLEControlObject (12), not msoTextBox (17). Are you sure that ` If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then` actually recognises the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the all the textbox in the sheets but if your textbox is on chartobject you need to handle it in a slightly different.

```
Sub TextBox()

    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim c As ChartObject
    Dim s As Shape

    For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each c In w.ChartObjects
            For Each s In c.Chart.Shapes
                If s.Type = msoTextBox Then
                    With s.TextFrame2
                        strTxt = .TextRange
                        .DeleteText
                        .WarpFormat = msoWarpFormat1
                        .WordWrap = True
                        .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
                        .TextRange = strTxt
                        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                        .TextRange.Font.Size = "8"
                    End With
                End If
            Next s
        Next c
    Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: This does work in that it shrinks the text massively, but is there anyway to add calibri 18 font as default?

Comment: @tj123 Try now.